# Probability that a random variable is between two adjacent order statistics

Tags: probability, order-statistics

Given a random variable $X$ and known (but arbitrary) associated distribution, is it possible to find the probability that it falls between two adjacent order statistics $Y_{(i)}$ and $Y_{(i+1)}$? That is, find $P(Y_{(i)} \le X \le Y_{(i+1)})$. Assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Finding the probability that $X$ is greater (or smaller) than one of these can easily be found due to independence: 
$$P(X \ge Y_{(i)})=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{x}f_{X}(x)f_{Y_{(i)}}(y)~dy~dx$$
But I run into the problem that $Y_{(i)}$ and $Y_{(i+1)}$ are not independent. How would you properly account for this in an expression for the probability?

Comment: Are your order statistics the standard ones, i.e., associated with a sorting of  $n$-uple $(X_1,\cdots X_n)$ where each $X_i$ is $Unif[0,1]$-distributed ?

Comment: Maybe this can be of some help : (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/405391).

Comment: See my recent answer to @JeanMarie's link.

Comment: Assuming a continuous distribution, and the $Y_{(i)}$ are ordered from an i.i.d sample size $n$, and the $X$ comes independently from the same distribution, I would guess this would be  $\frac{1}{n+1}$ since the $X$ is equally likely to be any of the gaps or the gaps before or after

Comment: @BruceET: See my recent answer to JeanMarie's link ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, as Henry detailed in a comment, that the $Y_{(i)}$ are ordered from an i.i.d. sample of size $n$ of the same distribution as $X$, we have

$$\mathsf P\left(Y_{(i)} \le X \le Y_{(i+1)}\right)=\frac1{n+1}\;,$$

since all $(n+1)!$ orders of the $n+1$ independent variables $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n,X$ are equiprobable and $X$ has each particular rank in a fraction $\frac1{n+1}$ of them.